# Node.js WriteStream Unknown Encoding error

Tags: node.js, encoding

I've created a module that parses NGinx logs, and now i am writing a command tool that uses it. My problem is that I allow a whole directory to be parsed, which is not a problem on the reading then parsing side, since I have a pool that qeueus up the reads and parsing, however, on the command line tool, I am allowing to rewrite the logs in a different format, JSON for now, - ok I will cut to the chase, I have writen this Writer object that will keep references of all the WriteStreams (wstreams[readFilePath] (I know I am using the readFilePath, this is just a key to look up), 
and there is also a global reference of all the reading streams through the module exposed object Parser.rstreams[readFilePath]

```
// creating a writer to handle the data buffering from the parser's readstreams
writer = {
wstreams: {},
append: function(data, wfile, rfile){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.wstreams[rfile]));
    if(this.wstreams[rfile] 
        && (this.wstreams[rfile].write(data, wfile) == false) // <-- crashing here 
        && parser.rstreams[rfile]
        && parser.rstreams[rfile].pause){
            console.log('Pausing: ' + rfile);
            parser.rstreams[rfile].pause();
    }
},
addStream: function(wfile, rfile){
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(wfile, {'flags': 'w', 'encoding':'utf8', 'mode': '0666'});
    console.log("stream added: " + wfile + " r: " + rfile);
    this.wstreams[rfile] = wstream;
    this.wstreams[rfile].on('drain', function(){
        if(parser.rstreams[rfile]
            && parser.rstreams[rfile].readable 
            && parser.rstreams[rfile].resume){
                console.log('Drained: ' + rfile);
                parser.rstreams[rfile].resume();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

When the a writeStream is trying to write data, it's throwing an Unknown Encoding exception, which makes no sens since it defaults to utf8, and even if I pass the optional encoding, it will do the same thing, I tried ut8, utf-8, and ascii

```
{"path":"/Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/bin/here.json","fd":8,"writable":true,"flags":"w","encoding":"utf8","mode":"0666","bytesWritten":0,"busy":false,"_queue":[],"_events":{}}
[GINX][ERROR][uncaughtException] Error: Unknown encoding
[GINX-DEBUG] Exiting - 0 {file:cursor} record(s) stored in /Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/tmp/stored.cursors

/Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/lib/ginx.js:453
throw err;
      ^
Error: Unknown encoding
at Buffer.write (buffer.js:382:13)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:261:26)
at WriteStream.write (fs.js:1548:12)
at Object.writer.append (/Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/bin/ginx.js:95:38)
at /Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/bin/ginx.js:152:16
at Ginx.eval [as hardParseLine] (eval at generateParseLine (/Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/lib/ginx.js:59:21))
at streamData (/Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/lib/ginx.js:179:13)
at Ginx.parseFile.fs.stat.stream.on.streamEnd.cursor (/Users/akhoury/code/rk/ginx/lib/ginx.js:346:28)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
at ReadStream._emitData (fs.js:1365:10)
```

I even JSON.stringify the stream to see what's in it, and it looks fine.

I looked at the source of buffer.js and it doesn't make sense, that error should occur when the encoding is none of the allowed list
    https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js :50's

then I have a loop that will read the directory, if directory, and then write.addStream(outputfile, inputfile)

```
if (stats.isDirectory()) {
fs.mkdir(output, function () {
    fs.readdir(input, function (err, files) {
        if (err) error(err);
        files.forEach(function (wfile) {
            wfile = path.join(output, file);
            rfile = path.join(input, file);
            console.log("W:"+ wfile + " R: " + rfile);
            //prepend the JSON openings for each new file before we go on.
            if (isNewFile(rfile)) {
                fs.writeFileSync(wfile, "{[", 'utf8');
            }
            writer.addStream(wfile, rfile); // <-- adding the stream to writer here
        });
        processDirectory(input, output);
    });
});
} else if (stats.isFile()) {
if (isNewFile(input)) {
    fs.writeFile(output, "{[", 'utf8', function () {
        writer.addStream(output, input);
        processFile(input, output);
    });
} else {
    writer.addStream(output, input);
    processFile(input, output);
  }
}
```

then in processFile and processDirectory, everytime I receive a rowCallback, which means a line has been parsed, I use writer.append

```
// process file parsing to JSON output
function processFile(input, ouput) {
parser.parseFile(input,

function (err, row) {
    if (err) error(err);
    writer.append(ifLastRow(row), output, row.__file);
},

function (err, rfile) {
    if (err) error(err);
    //close the JSON array
    writer.append("]}", output, file);
});
```

}

```
// process directory parsing to JSON outputs
function processDirectory(input, output) {
parser.parseDir(input,

function (err, row) {
    if (err) error(err);
    var fname = row.__fname;
    writer.append(ifLastRow(row), path.join(output, fname), row.__file);
},

function (err, rfile) {
    if (err) error(err);
    var wfile = path.join(output, rfile.substring(rfile.lastIndexOf(path.sep) + 1));
    //close the JSON array
    writer.append("]}", wfile, rfile);
},

function (err, filesCount) {
    if (err) error(err);
 });
}
```

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong here?
am I creating the stream the wrong way?

I know that's a lot to read but I didn't want to be too general. 
Thank you.

Comment: This is a lot of code to read. It would be nice if you could coin the smallest amount of lines of code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just didn't want to be ambiguous, 
the part that's crashing is in the first code block. Look for this line: `        && (this.wstreams[rfile].write(data, wfile) == false) // <-- crashing here`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

It looks like some complicated machinery to basically just implement `rfile.pipe(wfile)`.

Comment: @isaacs You're right, I am aware of .pipe() but my parser also handles mid I/O interruption - you could kill the program and resume the read/write where it left of. 
it's not the most beautiful thing i wrote but it works :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you are passing a filename as the second parameter to [stream.write()](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_write_string_encoding), but the second param to `.write()` is an optional encoding (see previous link).

The error is because it is trying to use the filename as an encoding, which is an `Unknown encoding`. If `data` is a buffer, then let it determine the encoding based on the buffer.

A write stream is tied to a file, so you don't need to pass the filename on each write. Try changing:

```
    && (this.wstreams[rfile].write(data, wfile) == false)
```

To:

```
    && (this.wstreams[rfile].write(data) == false)
```